# What can be found in the MT curves of superconductors?

Tags: superconductivity

I am confused about the magnetic susceptibility vs. temperature curves (MT) of superconductors (SCs).

In the normal conduction state (I measured from 4.5K to 300K), the susceptibility curve can obey the Curie-Weiss law. But when I fitted the data via the Curie-Weiss law in a  different temperature range, different results (effective  magnetic moment) came out.

How should I select the  temperature range in the normal state for fitting the curves with the Curie-Weiss law?

Also, I synthesized a series of SC samples with different Tc. How should I compare the susceptibility curves of SCs with different Tc? What physical properties can be concluded form those MT curves?

Comment: Can you show us the curves?                                                            
Those kinds of SC are you measuring?

Below Tc, susceptibility goes down.  The size of the diamagnetic moment is proportional to the superconducting volume fraction.  susceptibility should be -1, if 100% of volume is SC phase.  Also, critical current can be learned from hysteresis loop  (see beans model)